# Окошко с информацией в консольном приложении

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, boost

Пишу консольное приложение, которое будет запускаться из служб в скрытом режиме. Хочется иногда для каких-то ошибок делать выскакивающее окошко с информацией об ошибке. Возможно ли это и, если возможно, как реализовать?

P.S. Работа приложения не должна замораживаться из-за окошка.

PPS Окошко обычное с кнопкой "ОК" и можно еще пример с нотификацией в трее.

Comment: Какое окошко? Обычный диалог или в трее нотификацию?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов обычное. Но и в трее тоже понадобится.

Comment: Окно из службы - очень плохое решение. Как и уведомление в трей.
Ведь службы могут работать на сервере, где никто не залогинен, или наоборот залогинено несколько пользователей.
Хорошее решение - писать в события. + Можно сделать обычное пользовательское приложение, которое будет сидеть в терее, опрашивать сервис и показывать пользователю всё, что нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычное окошко — `MessageBox` в отдельном треде. Уведомление в трее — `Shell_NotifyIcon` и иже с ним. Только я не уверен, что в консольном приложении трэй будет корректно работать, не пробовал.

Comment: с_str в помощь. WinAPI - сишный интерфейс и ничего не знает о std::string.

Comment: LPCWSTR - юникодная строка, если вы хотите использовать ASCII смените поддержку юникода в настройках проекта или пробуйте явно указать тип функции: MessageBoxA

Comment: Ну тут надо смотреть как часто вам придется явно прописывать тип функции. Я в проектах меняю настройки в 99% случаев.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, [`MessageBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - это именно то, что вам нужно. Первый параметр функции ставьте `NULL`.

Через трей работать несколько сложнее, там уже не одна функция, но тоже вполне доступно из такого «консольного без консоли» приложения. У меня, по крайней мере, работает.